# Importing a JavaScript module which only contains extending prototypes

Tags: javascript, module

How can I export/import a JavaScript module which only contains extending prototypes? Lets take some code of my current project:

`hijacks.js`:

```js
/// @source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31810991/11186407
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
    let onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    let today = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate());
    let dayOfYear = ((today - onejan + 86400000) / 86400000);
    return Math.ceil(dayOfYear / 7)
};

/// @source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5210450/11186407
Date.prototype.getFirstWeekDay = function() {
    // strip time away and set date and time to the beginning of the week-day
    let curr = new Date(this.toDateString());
    curr.setHours(0);
    curr.setMinutes(0);
    curr.setSeconds(0);
    curr.setMilliseconds(0);
    let first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
    return new Date(curr.setDate(first));
}

/// @source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5210450/11186407
Date.prototype.getLastWeekDay = function() {
    // strip time away and set date and time to the end of the week-day
    let curr = new Date(this.toDateString());
    curr.setHours(23);
    curr.setMinutes(59);
    curr.setSeconds(59);
    curr.setMilliseconds(999);
    let first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
    let last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6
    return new Date(curr.setDate(last));
}

/// @source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5210450/11186407
Date.prototype.nextWeek = function() {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + 7);
}

/// @source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5210450/11186407
Date.prototype.previousWeek = function() {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() - 7);
}
```

How would I then import the module and make the extended methods available?
`main.js`

```js
import { ??? } from "./hijacks.js";
let d = new Date();
console.log(g.getWeek());
```

This is not a Question on how to include modules, but instead how to include a module which doesn't contain any exports.

Comment: FYI: This is not hijacking, this is how [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) were done before they existed in JS (ES5 and older).

Comment: Oh, good to know. I didn't knew the technical term and just assumed, that it was hijacking, as it is analogously called hijacking in other languages.

Comment: But I still don't know its technical term...

Comment: It is commonly referred to as *"extending prototype"*, *"[inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)"* or *"Monkey Patching"*

Comment: Side effect modules can just be imported using. -> `import "./hijacks.js";`

Comment: @Moritz "*This is not a Question on how to include modules, but instead how to include a module which doesn't contain any exports.*" - how is that not **exactly** answered by [the duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38398311/1048572)?

Comment: Sorry, it indeed answered the question. I just looked at the question and thought it was not the same as mine. But the first answer indeed solved my problem. Sorry for the inconvenience.